# Identifying Comparative Sentences

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am looking to identify comparative sentences in interviews. Can anyone here direct me towards a software or an idea of how to proceed?

Is there anything available on the Google Cloud Platform or Stanford NLP package?

Comment: Could you please clarify if comparative is in the context of "comparative Vs superlative" or sentences that are similar

Comment: @SidharthMacherla, sentences such as this: "our viewing is very large and growing, but nowhere near as big as YouTube's...” So, it would be comparative and superlative sentences. I am looking at GCP for solutions at the moment. But, can't find something that works.

Comment: Taking a look at https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/morphology there seems to be no direct way of getting that (not even workarounds like identifying comparative verbs or pronouns that modify adjectives in that way (like more). A feasible option would be use AutoML (pretrained models) in order to provide with some examples of what is a comparative sentence and then use your own generated model.